# Ssh connection fail with public key on port 22 but succed on port 2222

Tags: networking, ssh, debian

I’ve trouble to connect to a server with ssh. Everything works fine last week, and now the ssh server only accept password authentication and dosen’t allow public key.

The server with sshd is a Debian 9, and the client a LinuxMint. I have another server that has the same configuration as the one who bug and in this one, I can use a public key to connect with ssh.

So I check file permission on server and on the LinuxMint.

Permission on server:

```
drwx------ 2 plop plop 4,0K mai   24 12:10 .ssh
-rw------- 1   plop plop 750  mai   24 12:10 authorized_keys
```

I checked in the /*etc/ssh/sshd_config* if public key can be use.
I created a new rsa 4096b ssh key and copy to the server with ssh-copy-id.
I created a new user and add the ssh pub key.
I uninstalled and install again the *openssh-server*.
I rebooted the server and the client.

Nothing works. Each time I’ve try to connect, the ssh client prompt me for a password (it’s madness).

below the log of an ssh attemp connection:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/userami/.ssh/config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.10.10.02" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.10.02 [10.10.10.02] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/userami/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userami/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userami/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userami/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userami/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userami/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userami/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userami/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.10.10.02:22 as 'remoteusername'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/userami/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/userami/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.10.10.02
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:IW89ksNoqRYQMGDan+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/userami/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/userami/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.10.10.02
debug1: Host '10.10.10.02' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/userami/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/userami/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55a67a2bff40), agent
debug2: key: /home/userami/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/userami/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/userami/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug3: start over, passed a different list password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
remoteusername@10.10.10.02's password:
```

I’ve tried to launch the ssh deamon with debug log **/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222**, and on the 2222 port the ssh server accept my pubic key (Why ??).

So I’ve changed the port number in the sshd_config and restart the service, and now I can use the public key to connect on port 2222. But if I change back for 22, connection dosen’t work and ask for a password.

Why ssh server accept public key on 2222 port but not the default one ?

-- EDIT 1 --

As requested by Martin @Dmitriy Kupch

```
ss -tulpn | grep 22
tcp    LISTEN     0      128       *:2222                  *:*                   users:(("sshd",pid=7805,fd=3))
tcp    LISTEN     0      128      :::2222                 :::*                   users:(("sshd",pid=7805,fd=4))
```

The *lsof -i :22* didn't return anything.

Comment: I know it seems unlikely, but have you checked if there is another process using port number 22? Is the connection to port 22 refused when you switch ports, or shut down your SSH server?

Comment: Please provide the server log and the verbose output output of your ssh client (`ssh -vvv`) from your unsuccessful tries.

Comment: I checked if another process was using port 22, but no.

Comment: can you provide an output for:
```ss -tulpn | grep 22```
and
```sudo lsof -i :22```

Comment: If you listen to 2222 how do you expect for SSH to work on 22 ?

Comment: Where is your local ssh keypair?

Comment: My ssh Keypair are store in "~/.ssh" folder at the root of my Home folder (Linux Mint).